# how do i fix this rewrite URL rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

basically need to convert

with www or not, example.com/**[anycharacter]**

into

with www or not, example.com/cgi-bin/new-disk.cgi/dir/smooth/**[anycharacter]**

additinoally...

i would like to redirect ALL **www.example.com** into **example.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !cgi-bin/new-disk.cgi/dir/smooth
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/new-disk.cgi/dir/smooth/$1 [L]
```

For the first two lines, it checks to see if you have `www` in your URL. If so, bounce it to the non-www version.

Note the exclamation mark (`!`) on the second last line. This is a not operator and in this test, is checking to see if your currently requested file **isn't** your final rewriting file, in this case:

```
cgi-bin/new-disk.cgi/dir/smooth
```

If that's true, shunt it to the actual rewrite script you have as pointed out in the final line.

The character, **$1**, references the first capture group as marked by the first set of parentheses on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

For part of your answer, I believe you can use this as an example to base off.. hopefully you use a test domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Might need to add a `(.*)` and make it optional for the other part.